# Mastermind game : bugs fixing

Tags: python, debugging

I am coding MASTERMIND but facing one problem.

EXAMPLE :
secret code  = GGYR and user input = YGGG

it shows :
correct colour correct position = 1 , correct colour wrong position = 3

WHICH IS WRONG.

it should show :
correct colour correct position = 1 , correct colour wrong position = 2

The third 'G' shouldn't cause an addition in 'correct colour wrong position' since there are only two 'G' in the secret code.

HERE IS WHAT I CODED :

```
    #CHECK COLOUR ONE 
    if position1 in secret :
        correct_colour += 1
        if position1 == secret[0]:
            correct_answer += 1
            correct_colour -= 1
        elif position1 == secret[1]:
            if position1 == position2 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position1 == secret[2]:
            if position1 == position3 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position1 == secret[3] :
            if position1 == position4 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        
    #CHECK COLOUR TWO
    if position2 in secret :
        correct_colour += 1
        if position2 == secret[1]:
            correct_answer += 1
            correct_colour -= 1
        elif position2 == secret[0]:
            if position2 == position1 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position2 == secret[2]:
            if position2 == position3 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position2 == secret[3] :
            if position2 == position4 :
                correct_colour -= 1

    #CHECK COLOUR THREE
    if position3 in secret :
        correct_colour += 1
        if position3 == secret[2]:
            correct_answer += 1
            correct_colour -= 1
        elif position3 == secret[0]:
            if position3 == position1 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position3 == secret[1]:
            if position3 == position2 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position3 == secret[3] :
            if position3 == position4 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        
    #CHECK COLOUR FOUR
    if position4 in secret :
        correct_colour += 1
        if position4 == secret[3]:
            correct_answer += 1
            correct_colour -= 1
        elif position4 == secret[0]:
            if position4 == position1 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position4 == secret[1]:
            if position4 == position2 :
                correct_colour -= 1
        elif position4 == secret[2] :
            if position4 == position3 :
                correct_colour -= 1
```

is there anything I should add / remove / edit ?

PLEASE HELP ME      :(
have been stuck for days.

Answer (score 0):

Another shorter way to code this in python:

```
secret = "GGYR"
entry = "YGGG"

trueposition = list(map(lambda x, y: x==y, secret, entry))
truecolor = list(map(lambda x, y:  (x in secret) and (x!=y), secret, entry))

print(trueposition.count(True))
print(truecolor.count(True))
```

But this also output 1 correct, and 3 misplaced
Could you check the rules of the game ?

in "Y_GG" : Y is misplaced, G is missplcaed, the 2nd G is aslo missplaced ? or should it be ignored ?

Comment: Hello ! thank you for the advice. 
Yes, since the first G is already correct, it should only consider the second G and ignore the third G. 

Therefore, that is the problem i am facing.